# Char x[50] and Char x[100] Output

Tags: c, char, strcat

I'm not used to C as I'm primarily a Java guy, with some knowledge of C++, so forgive me if this is a trivial question. I could not seem to find an answer while searching online.

I'm initializing a char array...

```
char tcp[50];
```

So that I can concatenate a const char and a char. In examples I saw an easy way to do this was by creating that empty char array and then using...

```
strcat(x,y);
```

To stick them together.

Problem is, printing out the blank char array when it is set to "50" gives me a result of:

```
X??|?
```

When I change it to...

```
char tcp[100];
```

And print it, its blank. Why is this?

Comment: In c you explicitly need to terminate strings with the null (0x0) character.

Comment: Sorry, what is "concatenate a const char and a char"? That doesn't seem to make sense in this context. Also, are you sure you initialise the tcp array before strcatting something to it?

Comment: Since I can't edit the contents of the const char, I'm combining it with another char in a blank array. Or at least that was the plan.

Comment: You're not initialising the array at all. You merely declared it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The array contents are undefined, assuming it is a local (automatic) array.

Use:

```
char tcp[50] = "";
```

Or:

```
char tcp[50] = {0};
```

Or:

```
char tcp[50];
tcp[0] = 0;
```

Or:

```
char tcp[50];
memset(tcp, 0, sizeof(tcp));
```

As you like.

Answer (score 1):

Always null terminate you char arrays before doing anything:

```
tcp[0] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

C happily allocates the space for the array you declare, but it does not set its content to 0.

Therefore, the content of the array you're printing is random (or rather depending in the previous contents of the memory)

Answer (score 1):

When creating an array, the compiler puts it somewhere in memory but does not initialize it, so whatever is in that memory when the program is started will be the initial "string".

Terminate the string manually after you created the array, either by making the whole array "zeroed" out, or just put zero as the first character:

```
char tcp[50] = { '\0' };
```

Or

```
char tcp[50];
/* ... */
tcp[0] = '\0';
```

Comment: In the first snippet, `'\0'` is meaningless as all the following elements will happen to be zeroes anyway. If `'\1'` were the first-element initialiser, then all the following elements will still be zeroes. `{}` is clearer, given this.

Answer (score 0):

The difference here is, you're essentially working with two empty arrays trying to merge them in the memory space of one (not sure if that makes sense for you).

First of all, in C you have to terminate strings with `\0`. That's something not exposed or visible in Java. Also you essentially used two undefined strings (as there's no value set).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char target[256];
const char source_a[] = "Hello";
const char source_b[] = "World!";

int void(main)
{
    target[0] = '\0'; // this essentially empties the string as we set the first entry to be the end. Depending on your language version of C, you might as well write "char target[256] = {'\0'};" above.
    strcat(target, source_a); // append the first string/char array
    strcat(target, " "); // append a const string literal
    strcat(target, source_b); // append the second string

    printf("%s\n", target);

    return 0;
}
```

Important: Using `strcat()` can be unsave, as there's no length check performed, and other than Java, these "strings" have a fixed length (the one you set when defining the variables). If there's no length given, but you copy a string on initialization, that length is taken (e.g. `char test[] = "Hello!";` will be 7 chars long (due to terminating `\0`)).

If you'd like a more Java like approach on strings, use C++ and the `std::string` class, that performs a lot more similar to Java's strings.